# Matlab Programming : plotting susceptance vs firing angle alpha

Tags: matlab, plot, equation

I'm not that strong in programming. I was trying to plot two equations from Power Electronics in Matlab. My code is as follows. I am getting a blank plot when I plot Btcr and alpha! Kindly let me know whats wrong.

```
       Plotting Susceptance vs Firing Angle

%Variables
V = 1;
L = 0.005;
freq = 60;
omega = 2 * pi * freq;
theta = 0:0.01:360*2;

for alpha = 90:10:180
sigma = 2*(180 - alpha)
Btcr = (sigma + sind(2*alpha))/(omega*L*3.14);
end
plot(Btcr, alpha);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `for`-loop is unnecessary. You are actually overwriting the previous values of `sigma` and `Btcr` each time you go through the loop, so at the end you don't have vectors of data, just two numbers. You can fix this by removing the loop altogether:

```
alpha = 90:10:180
sigma = 2*(180 - alpha)
Btcr = (sigma + sind(2*alpha))/(omega*L*3.14);
plot(Btcr, alpha);
```

Comment: Thanks a tonne David! I'm getting the graph! But is there a way I can make the curve smooth? I'm getting a jagged line now.

Comment: @Som It looks fine to me, I get a pretty good straight line. Try plotting markers rather than a line (using `plot(Btcr,alpha,'o')`) to see whether the jagged-ness comes from the data or the plotting.

Comment: Thank you David. The markers looked better than the line.. :)